# Custom validation of Map<Locale, String> with Play Framework 1.2.5

Tags: validation, playframework-1.x

I use Play Framework 1.2.5 and use custom validation to a certain extend. I can't quite figure out how to do validation of a Map and report the error per field.

My entity has a description property, allowing the user to translate the description into any number of languages.

```java
public class MyEntity extends Model {
    ...

    @Valid
    public Map<Locale, String> description;

    ...
}
```

Basically my form contain a textarea per locale.

```html
<textarea rows="3" name="entity.description[en]" id="entity_description_en"></textarea>
<textarea rows="3" name="entity.description[da]" id="entity_description_da"></textarea>
```

I can get it to bind, but how do I validate the individual translations, and report any error on field level instead of just entity.description?

**UPDATE**:
I know that it can be done as part of the controller as seen below, but I would prefer if all validation was on the model only.

```java
public static void create(@Valid MyEntity entity) {
    validateMapKey("entity.description", entity.description, Locale.ENGLISH);
    validateMapKey("entity.description", entity.description, new Locale("da"));

    if(validation.hasErrors()) {
        params.flash(); // add http parameters to the flash scope
        validation.keep(); // keep the errors for the next request
        index();
    }

    ...     
}

private static void validateMapKey(String f, Map<Locale, ? extends Object> v, Locale l) {
    validation.required(String.format("%s[%s]", f, l), v.get(l));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@CheckWith](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/validation#anamecustomCustomvalidationusingCheckWitha) annotation can help you..

```java
@CheckWith(MyMapCheck.class)
public Map<Locale, String> description;

static class MyMapCheck extends Check {

    public boolean isSatisfied(Object myEntityInstance, Object descriptionValue) {
        return checkMyDescriptionAndReturnBoolean(description);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know @CheckWith. But how do I report the error on entity.description[en]? It seems to me that the error is reported on entity.description this way, and I can't figure out how to access the "entity.description"-context within a Check.

Comment: simply you cant. because `description` is being validated not **"the value on description map"**. You can make `description` as a seperate entity with `locale` and `text` fields. So than check `text` with its `locale`.

Comment: Okay. I looked at it quite a lot, and you confirmed my observations.